# Отладчик для Json в Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Я не могу найти нормальный отладчик Json для VSCode, нашел только 1 и то он не работает...
Если кто-то знает такой, можете пожалуйста скинуть ссылку?

Comment: json - это не исполняемый код, это данные. Его нельзя запустить и отлаживать.

Comment: Отладчик? Это же файл с данными, какой отладчик? Там только проверка синтаксиса имеет смысл.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Visual Studio Code "You don't have an extension for debugging 'Json with comments'. Shoud we find extension in store?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406294/visual-studio-code-you-dont-have-an-extension-for-debugging-json-with-comment)

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, что вы имеете в виду под "отладчиком", но VSCode умеет работать с json "из коробки", так как конфигурационные файлы для самого VSCode имеют данный формат.

В [официальной документации](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json) вы сможете найти целый раздел описывающий взаимодействие с данным типом файлов. Причем, VSCode поддерживает работу с json как с комментариями, так и без.

Работает `IntelliSense` и автоматическое форматирование (<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> для маков, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> для windows) и прочее

Comment: Ну смотрите, когда я пытаюсь запустить программу оно пишет это https://files.fm/f/85n69wj4w

Comment: @Ilyuxadwa как вы запускаете программу? Какую программу вы запускаете

Comment: @Ilyuxadwa ну и не нужно пытаться запустить json, он не программа.

Comment: Извините, может я немного глуповат но я пытаюсь сделать свою тему оформления для VS code, и запускаю пытался запустить launch.json но там выдавало ошибку, поэтому я её тоже тут задавал... Но мне сказали что не нужно его запускать и сказали просто сразу запустить программу и я начал запускать "Themes-color-theme.json"

Comment: @Ilyuxadwa json не является запускаемым и исполняемым файлом. Создание своей темы в vscode заключается в изменении настроек через json файл. Вопрос остается только в том, как вы заменяете эти json файлы, как вы пытаетесь это сделать, поскольку есть несколько возможностей и окружений где необходимо или возможно менять настройки. Запуск самого jsonа бессмыслен, поскольку он только описывает эти настройки

Comment: Ну смотрите, вот что мне сгенирировало и вот тут https://files.fm/f/gh8qmkvdr нужно все изменять, вот только вопрос как тогда  это запустить?

Comment: @Ilyuxadwa отлично, я вам предлагаю написать нормальный вопрос, в котором укажите, что вы делаете, как и какие команды (интерфейсы, пакеты, модули) вы для этого используете, какой результат вы ожидаете получить и какой результат у вас есть сейчас. Вы пишите "сгенерировало" - это совсем не понятно. Кто сгенерировал, почему это сгенерировано и проч.